# "this" pointer changes in GDB backtrace

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I am examining a core dump, and noticed that in one frame the 'this' pointer is different than in the next frame (in the same thread). Not just a little different, it went from 0x8167428 to 0x200.

I am not that well-versed in using GDB, but this does not seem right to me. Is this problematic, and if so, what could be the cause?

Comment: Can you add some code to your question reproducing this?

Comment: Unfortunately, this problem happens once every three days. Also, I have been unable to nail it down to a specific section of code (GDB says it happened while posting a semaphore, no pointers are referenced in that line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this` pointer can change between frames in a gdb trace if the function in the next frame is called on a different object (even if the objects are the same type), since this is for the specific instance.  This is probably *not* your problem.

`0x200` is not a valid value for `this`, and almost certainly indicates memory corruption of some type.  The `this` pointer is sometimes stored on the stack and passed as an invisible first argument to a function.  So if you have corrupted the stack (by going out of bounds writing to another variable) you could see the this pointer corrupted.

The value `0x200` itself is interesting.  Because it is so close to `0`, but not actually `0`, it indicates that the instance you're looking at is probably part of another object or array, located `0x200` bytes from the beginning of that object/array, and that the object/array's address is actually `NULL`.  Looking at your code you should be able to pretty easily figure out which object has gotten set to `NULL`, which is causing this to report `0x200`.

Comment: So, 0x200 is 512 in decimal. Does this mean I have to search for an object that is 512 bytes in size?

Comment: Not exactly.  You're looking for an object that contains at least 512 bytes, because this is at offset 512 from the beginning.  It could also be an array... if "this" is 128 bytes itself then it is the 4th index (5th element) of an array of these objects.  Or it could be some combination of the two.  but something, somewhere, is null.

Comment: This answer turned out to be close enough. There was a buffer close to the class for which the 'this' pointer changed that got zeroed out.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that an optimization in the code is confusing the debugger.  This is a common issue when debugging retail code.  Try disabling optimizations, re-running the scenario and see if you get the same problem.

Comment: @Hans, i meant compiler optimizations, not user ones.  Did you try disabling all compiler optimzations?

Comment: Sorry, that was what I meant as well. There are other shared objects used that are compiled with -O2

Answer (score 0):

`this` pointer is local to frame.

Is the other frame belongs to 'C' function, you could see smth like 0x200

Comment: Both frames are for functions of the same class.