# "this" pointer getting corrupted in stack trace

Tags: c++, qt4, this, memory-corruption, stack-corruption

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556945/this-pointer-changes-in-gdb-backtrace) thread. My case is slightly different and I'm struggling to figure out how `"this"` pointer is getting corrupted.

I'm using the Qt 4.6.2 framework, using their `QTreeView` with my own model. The backtrace I get (86 frames long, with a lot of recursion, that's why I haven't pasted the whole thing in, it's in this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/SSCrwRW5) only involves their code.

It finally segfaults on some assembler in QBasicAtomicInt::deref, but it's obvious that it has died further down, evidenced by these three frames:

```
#15 0x01420fd3 in QFrame::event (this=0x942bba0, e=0xbf8eb624) at widgets/qframe.cpp:557
#16 0x014bb382 in QAbstractScrollArea::viewportEvent (this=0x4, e=0x93f9240) at widgets/qabstractscrollarea.cpp:1036
#17 0x0156fbd7 in QAbstractItemView::viewportEvent (this=0x942bba0, event=0xbf8eb624) at itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp:1610
```

In frame 17, `this` is `0x942bb0`. In frame 16, `this` should be the same, as in frame 17 it's calling its ancestor's implementation of the same method. However `this` becomes 0x4.

Interestingly enough in frame 15 (again, frame 16 has called its ancestor's implementation of the same function), the 'this' pointer is restored to `0x942bba0`.

If you looked at the pastebin of the full backtrace, you might see some 'value optimized out'. I had the application compiled with optimization on; I now have gcc set to `-g3 -O0` so when it happens next time I might have something more. But of course now I can't make it crash -- it is a fairly difficult bug to make happen (but very important to fix nonetheless) so I don't think that's too suspicious.

Given the optimizations, is that `this` `pointer=0x4` unusual or definitely wrong? What is odd is that there's no real code in any of these viewportEvent frames -- they simply do a switch on the event's type, it falls through the switch statement, and it returns its ancestor's implementation.

Valgrind doesn't seem to be throwing up any issues, although I haven't made it crash in Valgrind yet.

Has anybody seen this behaviour before? What could be causing it?

Comment: +1, long back I had seen the same problem with my code; I don't know how I had fixed it; but reminds me of old times. :)

Comment: When you compile the code are there any warnings? Fix them first.

Comment: @iammilind: That's a reason for making this a favourite question (by clicking on the star), but not for up-voting it.

Comment: @phresnel, upvoted because, I am anxious to know the answer.

Comment: `this pointer=0x4` is definitely wrong. You never get stuff in the first page. What you need now is a reproducible test case -- or, at least, a core dump.

Comment: @iammilind: That's of course an upvote reason :)

Comment: @Martin: No warnings, apart from three instances where I'm not checking the return value of a system() call (don't really care if the shell process completes successfully or not)

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ: I have the core dump, that's what I'm picking my backtrace out of. What should I be going on from here?

Comment: What options are you using for the optimized build?  You might want to try selectively disabling some of the more aggressive optimization to see if they narrow down the possibilities. Like maybe try `-fno-strict-aliasing` if that's turned on in builds that show the problem.

Answer (score 8):

I have seen this sort of thing before when debugging optimized builds and it has never been an indication of what the real bug is for me.

It is easier to first think about a local variable.  In a non-optimized build, everything has its designated place in memory and must be stored after every line of code.  This is so the debugger can find it.  In an optimized build, values can live in registers without being written to memory.  This is a major part of the improved performance of an optimized build.  The debugger doesn't understand this and will always look at memory, so you will often see the wrong value.

The same can happen with parameters.  If the optimizer decides to pass a parameter in a register, the debugger is still going to look at the stackframe.  More specifically, at the location where the parameter would be according to the rules of the calling convention.

The fact that the next frame of the stack has the value properly restored indicates that the generated instructions are dealing with the this parameter correctly, but the debugger just doesn't know where to look for it.

Comment: Another variation on this is that even if the parameter is passed on the stack, the optimizer might repurpose the memory location for something else once it's done using the location for the parameter. So it's possible that `this pointer=0x4` in the backtrace is a red herring - especially if the `this` pointer parameter shows up correctly in lower numbered frames.

Comment: Thanks for the reponses. I've got optimization disabled now and have been working hard trying to make it crash again -- it's happening during a drag-and-drop on a treeview, particularly when the touchscreen is sending funny positions when you release finger pressure, so not so easy to automate! Hard to reproduce in the first place. Hopefully a non-optimised coredump will show some more useful results. Interesting. So in theory I could figure out what 'this' is supposed to be if I examined the assembler in the coredump and looked at the registers -- but that probably won't be helpful.